# ES6 import alias SOME exports not ALL

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I want to do this:

```
import { var1, var2, var3 } as Vars from './file';
```

Because I don't want ALL of the files, which I could accomplish using:

```
import * as Vars from './file';
```

Any reason this is not supported in ES6?

**edit:** Any workarounds? Bundler optimizations are more important than convenience.

Comment: Simply say `import { var1, var2, var3 } from './file'; var Vars = { var1, var2, var3 };`

Comment: I don't know why this is getting down voted - @mhodges that's a good work around, thanks, I'm still curious why I can't do this in ES6.

Comment: Try checking out [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2370). It may be helpful for answering your question of "why this is not supported?"

Comment: Probably because this isn't a sensible place to ask why something isn't in a language specification. That's a question for the spec  members.

Comment: @doodlemeister It's an answerable question with an opening for an explanation as to why what the OP is trying to do isn't supported. OP is not trying to change language spec, just trying to understand it and find a reasonable work-around. (I think?)

Comment: @mhodges: Seems like the question is pretty explicitly asking why is this not part of the spec. That's a reasonable curiosity for a programmer, but not a specific programming problem. Asking about a workaround would be, but I don't see that in this post.

Comment: this would be good to post at http://esdiscuss.org/1/

Comment: "I don't want ALL of the files" You're getting all the files either way. If a bundler could handle skipping files with your proposed syntax, it can probably handle `* as Vars` too just fine.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Webpack tree-shaking will do that. Using `* as Vars` will tell the bundler you are using everything, so include everything. Explicitly naming imports will tell Webpack to throw out all other imports from that file during the bundling process

Comment: @doodlemeister That's fair - I think the question could be edited to make that more explicit.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a bad question. With @mhodges suggestion, that pollutes the top level scope with `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, while it does not appear trivial to `import` them without having 3 variable names that end up being undesired in the scope.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I suppose if you're really concerned about scope pollution, you could set each of them to undefined immediately after setting the `Vars` object - although it seems tedious, I'm not sure there's a better work-around =\

Comment: @doodlemeister re: "this would be a good post at esdiscuss.org/1" - I agree that is a better place, I'll search there too. I came to SO to find an answer to my own question: Can I do this.. when I couldn't find it, I tested it out and learned that I cannot. Now I'm asking: Why CAN'T I do this; which now seems like the wrong type of question for SO, but If I came here for an answer so might someone else.

Comment: @mhodges Webpack strips it out as long as you don't use the object in a way that makes it impossible to know what imports are and aren't used. If all you do is `Vars.var1` it is perfectly able to see that `var1` is the only import that is used.

Comment: @Drew2 yeah generally SO discourages "why" questions about the specification unless there are very clear answers, like "Why did the specification for `parseInt`'s default behavior change", or "Why does the proposal for conditional property reference and invocation have to be something like `obj?.[prop]` and `func?.()` instead of `obj?[prop]` and `func?()`"? Both of those reasons are thoroughly discussed in various forums where decisions about ECMAScript are made.

Comment: @loganfsmyth This seems like an acceptable answer if it's in fact true (in what scenarios will webpack NOT strip it out?), and if I modify this question to ask more about the efficiency rather than the convenience.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I will keep this in mind when wording future questions, thanks.

Comment: @Drew2 if it's about efficiency, then there are duplicate answers on here I can search for if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your primary goal is specifically

> Because I don't want ALL of the files

rather than that you specifically want an object with a subset of the keys, then

```
import * as Vars from "foo";
```

should work fine.

```
import * as Vars from "foo";
Vars.var1();
```

makes it just as clear to Webpack that `var1` is the only import that is used as

```
import { var1 } from "foo";
var1();
```

would.

The primary place where this breaks down is if you do things that Webpack can't follow, like if you did

```
doThingWithImports(Vars);
```

then Webpack can't tell what imports `doThingWithImports` might be using and will have to load them all. Same if you had to do

```
Vars[arg]()
```

since it can't know what `arg` is.

> Any reason this is not supported in ES6?

Tree-shaking behavior is not part of the spec at all. If

```
import { var1, var2, var3 } as Vars from './file';
```

were a supported syntax, it would mean "Create an object with this subset of fields", but as far as the spec is concerned, you're still including every single dependency that is referenced inside of `./file`.

This means that at the end of the day it is the optimizations that a given bundler can perform that matters to you. Given that, the behavior of

```
import * as VarsAll from './file';
const Vars = { var1: VarsAll.var1, var2: VarsAll.var2, var3: VarsAll.var3 };
```

would be identical. And at that point, it's much more likely that the committee would pursue some syntax for picking properties off of objects into a new object, rather than adding a special-case syntax for imports only.

This type of syntax gets raised every once in a while, like https://esdiscuss.org/topic/extended-dot-notation-pick-notation-proposal as an example, but it hasn't caught on yet.

Comment: Actually, it would be great if `Vars` that is used with dot notation only still was be tree-shaken, while using `Vars` with brackets or as any other expression killed the optimization. I guess this applies to bundlers in the first place. Are you aware of any such initiatives?

Comment: @estus I'm not sure I understand. Webpack already does tree-shaking with dot notation.

Comment: "at the end of the day it is the optimizations that a given bundler can perform that matters to you" - Yep! Convenience is secondary, but also important. I'm going to accept this answer because it provides not only a workaround, but a better way to accomplish what I set out to do. I will modify my answer to the question to reflect that bundler optimizations and convenience are important.

Answer (score 0):

ES modules use strict syntax that can be statically analyzed. If you're using `import` syntax that isn't listed in [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you can be sure that it isn't supported.

`{ var1, var2, var3 } as Vars` generally doesn't make much sense, because `var1`, etc. is already imported and can be used as is; `Vars` namespace just adds extra bytes to minified code.

If a subset of a module is consistently needed and provides benefits (unused named imports can be tree-shaken), intermediate `file-subset` module can be added:

```
export { var1, var2, var3 } from './file';
```

It can be used then instead of `file`:

```
import * as Vars from './file-subset';
```

Comment: Yes, but the `Vars` namespace also prevents scope pollution, and I'd prefer not to create a file with a subset of the exports, although it's a good workaround as well.